# DRY running of chess move checks

Tags: javascript, chess

I have a switch statement that is checking the validity of pieces moves in chess. If a move looks valid I let flow continue and, if the move didn't cause a statement to `return false` the ending statement of the function is `return true`. I have code to handle the checking of bishop and castle moves but am struggling to find a DRY way to run both sets of tests against the queen:

```
switch (from_piece[0]) {
    case this.CASTLE:
        if (from[0] === to[0]) {
         //continue to run checks
        } else if (from[1] === to[1]) {
         //continue to run checks
        } else {
            return false;
        };
        break;
    case this.BISHOP:
        if (Math.abs(from[1] - to[1]) === Math.abs(from[0] - to[0])) {
         //continue to run checks
        } else {
            return false;
        };
        break;
    case this.QUEEN:
     // run both bishop and castle tests
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That logic is too complicated to do with only a switch statement. You can move the tests into functions and call them like so:

```
switch (from_piece[0]) {
    case this.CASTLE:
        validRook()
        break;
    case this.BISHOP:
        validBishop();
        break;
    case this.QUEEN:
       validRook();
       validBishop();
       break;
}
function validRook(){
    if (from[0] === to[0]) {
          return true;
    } else if (from[1] === to[1]) {
          return true;
    } else {
          return false;
    }
}
function validBishop(){
    if (Math.abs(from[1] - to[1]) === Math.abs(from[0] - to[0])) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget the `return` statements in the switch block, e.g. `return validRook();`, `return validBishop();` and  `return validRook() || validBishop();`